# How to do scheduling using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

## The Problem

> Given `N` input `vector = [x1, x2, ..., xl]` and each of them have same length `L`. Define `F = summation of N input vector`.
>   And the aim is to find a set of integer `T = [n1, n2, ..., nN]` represents delay of each input vector so that the maximum value of `F` is minimized.

## Example

Assume 2 Input vector `[0, 3, -1, 1, 0]`, `[0, 2, -1, 0, 0]`:

if `T = [0, 0]`, then `F = [0, 5, -2, 1, 0]` and `max(F) = 5` which is obviously not a good result.

if `T = [1, 0]`, so that `F = [0, 2, 2, -1, 1, 0]`, `max(F) = 2`. This T is we aim to find. The computing process below may help understand this problem:

`T = [1, 0]
Vector1 with delay 1     [0, 3, -1, 1, 0]
Vector2 with delay 0  [0, 2, -1, 0, 0]

F =                   [0, 2, 2, -1, 1, 0]`

## The Question

Any idea how to delay vector T using dynamic programming?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the result just be N x zero? Then max(F)would be 0, which is better than your example result.

Comment: @fafl the result T actually means horizontally shift input vector(i) and then make the summation.